# Outlook Mail API: How to select a Specific Property from a Message?

Tags: outlook, outlook-api

Every Outlook Message Payload has a Sender Attribute:

```
        "Sender": {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Name": "FirstName LastName",
                "Address": "bob@gmail.com"
            }
        }
```

And can be selected for via

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$select=sender

But how would one go about selecting for Sender.EmailAddress.Address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joggling with terms. According to API documentation for [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#message) The list of properties indicate you are able to select from the message 'Sender' (or 'From') **property**. This is exactly what you do. The return **type** of those properties is '[Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Recipient)' with is corresponding to the property 'EmailAddress' with **complex type** of '[EmailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EmailAddress)'. This type include two properties on it's own 'Name' and 'Address'. This is exactly what your example JSON displays.

> But how would one go about selecting for Sender.EmailAddress.Address?

You are able to select the **property** of the message (see above description and the API reference for the properies of the message). If property type is complex, you need to deal with it in your code. In fact this particular property is very trivial JSON and you just access the property of the object via objects accessor (.) or with brakets notation ([]).

Comment: Cool - I figured that, but was just wondering if I could bypass the need to access the property in my code.